# Single word for "invisible helper"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word with the meaning "invisible helper"? It's like we don't know that person but he helps us. I am looking for a single word which can substitute it.

Comment: If _guardian angel_ works, then _fairy godmother_ might work, too (particularly in the realm of children's literature). There's also the _angel on my shoulder_, if you're talking about helpful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind is a [*guardian angel*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guardian_angel):

> A spirit believed to protect and to guide a particular person.

Comment: guardian angel is like a guru.. right?

Comment: @pahnin: not exactly, I wouldn't claim that. Also, I've heard it used not only for spirits/angels, but also for people. I think you don't have to be spiritual to use the word :)

Comment: @FrantišekStanko Indeed, I believe this is the origin of *angels* to denote the investors in a Broadway production, who put up the money but remain (or at least the artists hope they remain) invisible behind the Producer.

Answer (score 1):

Another concept, much like a *guardian angel* is [spirit guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_guide), described as

> an entity that remains a disincarnate spirit in order to act as a guide or protector to a living incarnated human being